# Rails & Mongoid : user owner and user member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a application with these relations :

- a User can create many projects
- The owner can invite other Users as members
- If the user accept owner invitation he become a member, if he decline, nothing happened.

Right now, here is the models :

**project.rb**

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :client, type: String
  field :deadline, type: String

  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', inverse_of: :projects
  has_many :members, :class_name => 'User', inverse_of: :projects
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""
  field :username, type: String, default: ""

  # Invitations
  field :project_invitations, type: Array, default: []

  has_many :projects, inverse_of: :user

end
```

And here is the **invites_controller.rb**, for managing all invitation system (accept / decline invitation, create invitations and more) :

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

    def new 
        @invite = Invite.new(email: params[:search], sender_id: current_user.id)
    end

    def create
        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        recipient = User.find_by(email: params[:search])
        @invite = Invite.new(email: params[:search], sender: current_user.id, recipient: recipient, project_id: @project, accepted: false)
        if @invite.save
            flash[:success] = 'the invitation is sent'
            recipient.push(project_invitations: @invite._id )
            recipient.save
            redirect_to project_path(@project)
        else
            flash[:error] = 'something went wrong'
            puts @invite.errors.full_messages
            render :back
        end
    end

    def accept
        @invite = Invite.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
        @user = current_user
        @invite.accepted = true
        @user.project_invitations.delete(@invite._id)
        @invite.save
        @user.save
        @project.member = @user
    end

    def decline
        @invite = Invite.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
        @user = current_user
        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        @invite.accepted = false
        @user.project_invitations.delete(@invite._id)
        @invite.save
        @user.save
    end

end
```

Here is the question :

- In my project model I have :owner and :members, how can the user who accept the invitation could become :member of the project ? I write `has_many :members`, but I don't know how to set a normal user to become a :member ..

**EDIT**

Do you think it should be a good Id to create an array field where I'll put all users_id (who are members) ?

Thank !

Comment: Don't use arrays where you should use associations.

Answer (score 1):

Membership is in relation to a particular project.  Your project has many members, and needs to reflect that somehow in it's data structure.  I envision a members table with a bunch of user foreign keys and project foreign keys.  Then you can try to find member by userID and projectID to determine if they are a member at any point? Not really sure here though, I'm fairly inexperienced so I'm interested to hear what other people say.

Comment: hey buddy ! You think that I should create a new model : member.rb with project_id and all user who are members in ?

Comment: What do you think about creating an array field for getting all user_id in ? (all user who are invited)

Comment: i looked this up when writing my first answer.  I don't think an array should be stored in a table, if that is what you are asking.  That is generally code-smell that means you need a new relational table.  But a member model seems feasible, with at least user_id and project_id as foreign keys.  Get it to working at least, I did a similar thing with an "attendance-tracker" where an attendance was the cross between a user and an event.

Comment: Ok I think i've understand ! I have to create a model with association (belongs_to :user, belongs_to :project) and for each member I'll have a new line in my DB that match the project ID and the user ID, that is what you think ?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the initial approach I would take to it, similar to an event attendance project I built in rails recently.